# New version of Script# 0.6 and ASP.NET Ajax - where is MicrosoftAjaxExt.js?

Tags: script#

we use the ASP.NET Ajax (ie. `<asp:ScriptManager />`) on our pages and we wish to use Script# for generating js files with a client side functionality. The problem is when we include mscorlib.js into a page. In that moment other js libraries, which rely on ASP.NET Ajax, stop working.

Since Script# v0.6 sscorlib.dll and aacorlib.dll libraries were merged into mscorlib.dll. In [release notes](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/ReleaseHistory) is said *"Merged sscorlib.dll and aacorlib.dll into mscorlib.dll. Changed sscorlib.js to become mscorlib.js. If you are using ASP.NET Ajax, you need to include **MicrosoftAjaxExt.js** for equivalent functionality"*.

Where do we find this library?

Thanks for reply!!!

Answer (score 1):

Script# doesn't support ASP.NET Ajax anymore (starting with more recent builds).

You'll find mscorlib to be a much smaller runtime footprint than MicrosoftAjax.js (+ MicrosoftAjaxExt.js). There are plans to further reduce the size of mscorlib down significantly.

Along with jQuery it provides a better model for writing client apps.