# How to use Asp.Net Ajax with ScriptSharp?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, script#

Recently we have decided to update our project to the latest version  of Script#. We are heavily using MS Ajax library, but in the current Script# release there is no Sys namespace anymore.

Could anyone provide a way how to use Asp.Net Ajax with ScriptSharp 0.7.x?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script# doesn't support ASP.NET Ajax starting from version 0.6. For more details see [this](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/issues/181) official answer or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027665/new-version-of-script-0-6-and-asp-net-ajax-where-is-microsoftajaxext-js) one.

So, probably the best option here would be  to migrate from MS Ajax to jQuery library as were suggested in previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using latest [Script#](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp) successfully with Ajax.  jQuery namespace is jQueryApi.  If you [download the whole distribution from github](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp), there are some good samples, such as PhotoDemo that illustrate Ajax among other things.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what i meant. I was talking about this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536.aspx . Alas there is no support for tis in Scrip# anymore